# Sub-Controls for custom widgets in Qt

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

in Qt it is possible to use sub-controls to style widgets, that are part of another widget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#sub-controls

For example: With `QDockWidget::close-button`, I can set the style for a button in a QDockWidget.

Now I want to create my own button for a Widget. It is possible to call it in the qss-stylesheet with the sub-control syntax `MyWidget::my-button`, too how to set these sub-control command to the button?

best regards

Comment: Why don't you set the style of my-button directly, instead through its parent widget?

Comment: Here is an discussion on this: https://forum.qt.io/topic/5222/custom-sub-controls-for-custom-widgets-in-style-sheets It is rather old, but I think the things didn't change very much since then and it is still relevant:

Comment: did it work by styling directly the child widget?

Comment: Yes of course, this works and that's the current solution. The reason for these question is the style syntax only .

Comment: I see. Well, according to the links, it is the only solution.